# Getting Popular Searches In Magento

Tags: magento

I want to display the top 10 searches on my Magento store. Magento already stores searches made on the store under Admin > Catalog > Search Terms, so it's just a matter of getting it into my view. Does anyone know which helper or function I can access to get this list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a setPopularQueryFilter method in the class Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Mysql4_Query_Collection, after that you only have to set a limit I guess :)

Without trying, it should be something like that :

```
$searchCollectino=Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->getCollection()
     ->setPopularQueryFilter()
     ->setPageSize($limit);
```

Comment: It works! Just do a ->getItems() on the Collection and you get all the Items you want :)

Comment: +1 worked like charm :) @KeenoraFluffball that items will not be sorted according to their popularity.

Comment: In that case it must be coincidence all the time, cause mine are sorted correctly.

Comment: Maybe version issue? It's 2,5 years old ;)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs the Magento 2 solution:

inject the class `\Magento\Search\Model\Query` in your constructor and then retrieve the collection like so:
`$collection = $this->query->getSuggestCollection()`

This  will return a collection of most popular search terms sorted by the popularity.