# Not Getting Popular Searches In Magento Using Code

Tags: magento, search, magento-1.7

How to Get Popular Search Terms on Homepage ??

I have Referenced Following Question :
[Getting Popular Searches In Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434116/getting-popular-searches-in-magento)

So, I have used same code as given as below :

```
$searchCollectino=Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->getCollection()
 ->setPopularQueryFilter()
 ->setPageSize($limit);
```

They told that using ->getItems() we can get search terms.

But I am not getting what exactly the code can be..??

How to use this code ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Got Top 5 Popular Search Terms By Following Code :

```
$searchCollection = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->getCollection()
 ->setOrder('popularity', 'DESC');
$searchCollection->getSelect()->limit(8);
foreach ($searchCollection as $item)
{  
    echo $item->getData('redirect');
    echo $item->getData('query_text');
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but this did `$searchCollectino=Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->getCollection()
     ->setPopularQueryFilter()
     ->setPageSize($limit);` taken from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5435234/1577396).

Answer (score 1):

```
`$searchCollection = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->getCollection()
 ->setOrder('popularity', 'DESC');
 $searchCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);
 $searchCollection->getItems();`
```

This would fetch the popular searches with limit

Hope you enjoy it :)

Comment: with which method i can print the search terms ? 
Means foreach($searchCollection->getItems() as $terms){ echo $terms->***what to write here***(); }

Comment: Your answer is also available on other sites, those i have already referred.